# Why is Adobe Illustrator not letting me position anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, outline

I'm using Adobe Illustrator 2020.
I just can't make points align. Notice I don't want to merge the lines. I want to make an anchor point of one line match/align with the another point of another line.

When I release the point over the other one (when Illustrator smart guides is noting an *anchor*), the point goes elsewhere. But it doesn't want to touch the other point.
I even created a new file to see if the file I was working on was the problem, but it keeps happening.

Here a video of me struggling:
[image]

Comment: looks like gridsnap or pixel snap is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pixel grid in Illustrator, you don't always see it (depending on settings), but its there. Looking at the way it moves around, you probably have pixel snapping turned on. Check your snapping options at the bottom of the View main menu. Turn all of them **off**.

Comment: Well yes, those were on, thanks. So the reason of this to exist is to make the points to anchor to this invisible grid? Do you know the reason of its existence?

Comment: I never use the pixel grid, but it is probably useful for specific tasks.

Comment: Okay, choosing you as right answer because you told me where are those options..

Answer (score 2):

If you check View, make sure you have Smart Guides checked but other options such as Snap to Grid, Snap to Pixel, etc. are not checked. With the "Snap to"'s on, it will limit where the point gets set to unless you input the exact x and y coordinates in the properties panel.